# How to loop through an array of objects in PHP

Tags: php

On a quiz page, I have a JSON object that I have passed to my PHP script through ajax, containing the IDs of the questions paired with the provided answer.

Here's an example of how the array looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [questionId] => 2 [answerID] => q2-D [answerValue] => The World Wide Web Consortium ) [1] => Array ( [questionId] => 36 [answerID] => q36-A [answerValue] => <h6> ) )
```

What I want to do is loop through this array of objects and each time get the question ID and the answer value.

I have tried this code and it throws me an error:

```
$answers = $_POST["answers"];

foreach($answers as $i){
    $answer = $i->answerValue;
}
```

> Warning: Attempt to read property "answerValue" on array in path\to\script\calcul.php on line 9

**EDIT:**

Here's the AJAX function:

```
            $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var answers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("responses"));
            $.ajax({
                url:"./calc.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{
                    answers: answers,
                },
                success:function(data){
                   $("#response").html(data);
                }
            })
        });
```

And here's how the JSON object looks like in the localStorage:

```
[{"questionId":"2","answerID":"q2-D","answerValue":"The World Wide Web Consortium"},{"questionId":"36","answerID":"q36-A","answerValue":"<h6>"}]
```

Comment: Not reproducible. Show the JSON and your full code.

Comment: Show a `var_export($answers);` result

Comment: As it's an array - `$i['answerValue']`

Comment: var_export($answers) gives me this result:
array ( 0 => array ( 'questionId' => '2', 'answerID' => 'q2-D', 'answerValue' => 'The World Wide Web Consortium', ), 1 => array ( 'questionId' => '36', 'answerID' => 'q36-A', 'answerValue' => '<h6>', ), )

Comment: $i['answerValue'] seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an `array` and not an `stdObject` you need to access the elements with their index

```php
foreach ($answers as $i) {
    $questionId = $i['questionId'];
    $answerValue = $i['answerValue'];
}
```

Comment: I have tried your proposed solution but unfortunately, it didn't work. Throws me this error instead: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given

Comment: @Aschu Reason it didn't work is because it is automatically converted by the server from JSON to PHP's array for you.

Comment: @nice_dev @Aschu which servers automatically decodes the json string. I use `apache` and I have always had to decode it manually. Maybe somehow a `Content-Type` header is being sent and the server decodes it automatically. That does not happen on my setup though!!

Comment: @endeavour I'm using Apache too and apparently it's decoding it for me automatically. Perhaps you'll need to update it.